# Ping ip's in a dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict ({'ip': '10.198.0.12'}, {'ip': '10.198.0.91'}) and so on.

I have to ping the ip's in a dict one by one and see if it is pingable.
I am using the **pyping** python library but the i get an error saying
" dict object has no attribute split "

I am fetching the ip's from database using rows=cursor.fetchall() method and returning variable rows to my function ping_ip.

```
def ping_ip(values):
  ip_used_list=[]
  ip_free_list=[]
  for ip in values:
   response = pyping.ping(ip)
    if response.ret_code == 0:
     ip_used_list.append(ip)
     print("reachable", ip)
    else:
     ip_free_list.append(ip)
     print("unreachable", ip)
  return ip_free_list
```

Comment: Okay.... so what is your question?

Comment: You don't have a dict; you have a tuple of dicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you question, you don't have "a dict of IPs". What you have is a `set` of `dict`s that have a property `ip` that holds an IP address.

To ping, you only need that `ip` property of the `dict`s that are inside the `set`.

```
for ip_dict in values:
    response = pyping.ping(ip_dict['ip'])
```

Or, if you only want to work with the actual IP numbers and forget about the `{'ip': ''}` part, you could convert them into a `list` first.

```
def ping_ip(values):
    values = [x['ip'] for x in values]
    ...
```

That gives you a list of IPs like `['10.198.0.12', '10.198.0.91', ...]` to iterate over.

Comment: thanku:) . I now get o/p as ('unreachable', '10.135.0.10')
I now want a list of all unreachable and reachable ip's separately. How to do that ?

Comment: That's simple, but you need to clarify your question. What exactly does the tuple `('unreachable', '10.135.0.10')` mean? Is the IP `10.135.0.10` unreachable? Or was the unreachable IP string replaced by the word "unreachable", and all intact IP strings are the ones that *are* reachable?